Is there a way to test connection to web in powershell, with and without certificate?
I know that if the web service was installed with certificate, thus simple test connection in powershell like Invoke-WebRequest to that https site can give me whether it's possible to connect there or not. However I am wondering whether it's possible to test connection to that web without the certificate, like can it happen that connection will fail with certificate but will succeed without, because of certificate validation reasons?
Since I already can connect to that web with Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://..." -UseBasicParsing -TimeoutSec 10, I am wondering whether it's possible to somehow to test the connection without certificate.
UPDATE: What helped was adding this custom certificate policy after trying to connect securely
add-type @" public class AcceptAllCertificatePolicy : System.Net.ICertificatePolicy { public bool CheckValidationResult(System.Net.ServicePoint srvPoint, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate, System.Net.WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) { return true; } } "

this way even if site connection was insecure it could still get a response

Have you tried specifically testing http:// rather than https://?

Hi @KeithLangmead I tried that, but that doesn't seem to work since the web is already registered as https, what I found I could maybe try setting policy restrictions like this add-type @"
public class AcceptAllCertificatePolicy : System.Net.ICertificatePolicy {
public bool CheckValidationResult(System.Net.ServicePoint srvPoint, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate, System.Net.WebRequest request, int certificateProblem)
{ return true; }
}
"@
so that it accepts invalid certificates as well and is able to connect, but not sure if thats valid.

Are you asking how to detect that a site is listening on TCP443 but is not actually using HTTPS? This would be very unusual, so perhaps I'm misunderstanding the request.

Well I was rather asking whether the connection to site is secure or not like whether we can connect there either way.

You can inspect the remote certificate in PowerShell as follows:
# Extracted portion of https://github.com/Mike-Crowley/Public-Scripts/blob/main/OSINT/Request-AdfsCerts.ps1

function Get-SSLCertificate {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$Url,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [string]$HostHeader
    )

    begin {
        if ($PSVersionTable.PSEdition -ne "Desktop") {
            Throw "This function requires Windows PowerShell (Desktop edition)."
        }

        # If no host header provided, extract from URL
        if (-not $HostHeader) {
            $uri = [System.Uri]::new($Url)
            $HostHeader = $uri.Host
        }
    }

    process {
        try {
            [Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = { $true }

            # Make HTTPS connection and get content
            $request = [Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($Url)
            $request.Host = $HostHeader
            $request.AllowAutoRedirect = $false

            $response = $request.GetResponse()

            # Extract the certificate from the request
            if ($null -ne $request.ServicePoint.Certificate) {
                $HttpsCertBytes = $request.ServicePoint.Certificate.GetRawCertData()

                # Extract HTTPS cert
                $CertInBase64 = [convert]::ToBase64String($HttpsCertBytes)
                $Cert_x509 = [Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($CertInBase64))

                Write-Output $Cert_x509
            }
            else {
                Write-Warning "No Certificate Found at $Url"
            }
        }
        catch {
            Write-Error "Error retrieving certificate: $_"
        }
        finally {
            if ($null -ne $response) {
                $response.Close()
            }
        }
    }
}

Sample outputs:
# Returns:
# WARNING: No Certificate Found at http://example.com
Get-SSLCertificate -Url http://example.com

# In PS 6+ returns an error:
# This function requires Windows PowerShell (Desktop edition).
Get-SSLCertificate -Url https://example.com

# Returns:
#     Thumbprint                                Subject
#     ----------                                -------
#    4DA25A6D5EF62C5F95C7BD0A73EA3C177B36999D  CN=www.example.org, O=Internet Corporation for Assigned Names and Numbers, L=Los Angeles, S=California, C=US
Get-SSLCertificate -Url https://example.com

